# Use the numbers 8 6 4 2 = 25

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Use the numbers 8,6,4,2 and the operators +,-,*,/ to get 25.

You can use each number once.

Each operator can be used once.

The least number of operators you use the better answer will be.

Comment: mabye you want to add the no computer tag, since many people have written a bit of code to get 100 or 1 with the numbers 0-9 and those operators so it will be trivial to do this. Also, maybe add the condition: "with the least number of operators" because this will probably have multiple solutions

Comment: may be 4*(6+(2/8))

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Put that in an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati post it as answer

Comment: We have 4 numbers, 4 operators. All those operators need 2 arguments. One of the operators isn't used?

Comment: @leoll2 you can use only 3. I dont specify that you have to use all of them

Comment: Check out --- http://ask.metafilter.com/36897/Maths-powers-failing-me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer of this question is

> **4*(6+(2/8))**

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution, just with 2 operators:

> (98+2)/4=25, where 6 is upside down

Comment: This would be a good answer if there was a "lateral thinking" tag but these kinds of answers can get overwelming on questions that don't have that element.  Still entertaining answer this time though.

Comment: If this answer is valid, so is 29-4.

Answer (score -4):

> They are all even numbers. No matter what u do the answer has to be an even number.  It could be (8*6+4)/2=26 etc

Comment: Puzzling.SE is a bit different from other StackExchange sites, but we're still a question and answer site. Please read the existing answers before posting your own. 
You aren't improving the quality of the site by posting that a question can't be answered 3.5 years after an answer has been posted and accepted.

Comment: division leads out from the territory of even numbers, just think about 6/2 or using all the digits (8*4+6)/2 for example